# Excel VBA: Paste user input into a month column which is decided by the user

Tags: excel, vba, copy, paste

I'm very new to VBA programming and I have spent all afternoon googling how to do it and haven't been successful.

I have a spreadsheet with columns for months Jan-Dec.  What I'm trying to do is to have a user input some values and designate a month that the value should be pasted into.  For example: 1,2,3,4  and October.  And I expect October column to have 1,2,3,4 in it.

My newbie idea was to have TWO fields for input one with the values, and one which asks to input name of the month. Then record a macro with copies the input for the month, uses find feature to find the column which matches the input, then go one line below and then paste the values.  However because the cells aren't dynamic, it doesn't paste it into the correct cell.

This is the portion of the code which I've been using and where the issue occurs.  However I do not think this is the most efficient.

```
  ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 1
Range("F2:G2").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Range("F2:G2").Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets("2017 Agency Attendence").Select
Cells.Find(What:="november", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
    LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
    MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate
Range(N2).Select
```

Answer (score 0):

This should probably work for what you're doing. I've tried to comment what the program is doing to help you see how it works.

--Most people can convert a month into a number fairly quickly, so instead of writing an intense code to look it up, I just had the user enter a number.

--The user will then enter a string of numbers that are delimited (seperated) by commas. There is a function built into VBA - the [Split Function] (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6x627e5f(v=vs.90).aspx) - that will turn the delimited string into an array.

--Granting that a user will probably want to add data more than once, we need to find the bottom of any existing data and then paste your array of data after that.

```
Sub FindMonth()

'Initialize Variables
Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim monthNumber As Integer
Dim monthNumberVar As Variant
Dim inputString As String
Dim inputArray As Variant
Dim rowNumber As Long
Dim i As Long
Dim j As Long

Set sht = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
monthNumber = 0

'Prompt for month number
Do
    monthNumberVar = InputBox("Please enter number of month", "Month")

    'Make sure the input is a number
    If IsNumeric(monthNumberVar) Then
        monthNumber = Val(monthNumberVar)
    Else
        MsgBox "Please enter a NUMBER"
    End If
    If monthNumber < 1 Or monthNumber > 12 Then MsgBox "Please choose a number between 1 -12"

Loop While monthNumber < 1 Or monthNumber > 12

'Prompt for a list of the data//Turn that data into an array
inputString = InputBox("Please enter data seperated by commas", "Input")
inputArray = Split(inputString, ",")

'Find the first empty row in the column
i = 1
Do
    rowNumber = i
    i = i + 1
Loop Until sht.Cells(i, monthNumber).Value = ""

'Loop through the array and print out starting at row
For j = 0 To UBound(inputArray, 1)
    sht.Cells(i, monthNumber) = inputArray(j)
    i = i + 1
Next j

'Success Message
MsgBox "Data successfully placed"

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi,  Thank you very much for helping me work on this.  I couldn't get it to work the way I wanted it to but it's great to see code written out like this so I can tweak it to do what I need it to.  I appreciate it :)